# open cv3.1, python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, opencv3.1

I am trying to do face recognition using opencv3 and python3:
here is my code :

```
import errno
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import sys
import errno
os.chdir("E:\work\data")

face=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
def read_images(path):
    x,y=[],[]
    c=0
    for (dir,dirs,files) in os.walk(path):
        for folders in dirs:
            spath=os.path.join(dir,folders)
            print(spath)
            for file in os.listdir(spath):
                fpath=os.path.join(spath,file)
                img=cv2.imread(fpath,0)
                x.append(np.asarray(img,dtype=np.uint8))
                y.append(c)
        c=c+1
   return [x,y]






def face_rec():
    names=['Eldhose','Peter']
    read_images("E:\work\data")
    y=np.asarray(y,dtype=np.int32)
    model=cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
    model.train(np.asarray(x),np.asarray(y))
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    while True:
        suc,frame=cap.read()
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
        for (a,b,c,d) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(a,b),(a+c,b+d),(255,0,0),2)
        roi=gray[b:b+d,a:a+c]
        roi=cv2.resize(roi,(200,200),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        params=model.predict(roi)
        print("Label:%s,confidence %.2f" %(params[0],params[1])
    cv2.imshow("camera",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff

face_rec()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Its showing error .I am a beginner. I am weak in basics.
one of the errors were cv2.imshow("camera",frame)
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Please help me .
Thanks in advance :)

`

Comment: I am assuming you copied and pasted this from somewhere since this isn't exactly what a beginner would be able to come up with without knowing how to solve a syntax error. Would you mind posting where you got it from? Also, have you configured OpenCV correctly and know it is working? Try just importing cv2 and seeing if you experience any errors.

You also really need to just paste all of the errors out if there are more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## OpenCV_test1.py

## this program opens the file in the same directory names "image.jpg" and displays the original image and a Canny edges of the original image

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

#

def main():
    imgOriginal = cv2.imread("image.jpg")               # open image

```
if imgOriginal is None:                             # if image was not read successfully
    print "error: image not read from file \n\n"        # print error message to std out
    os.system("pause")                                  # pause so user can see error message
    return                                              # and exit function (which exits program)
# end if

imgGrayscale = cv2.cvtColor(imgOriginal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)        # convert to grayscale

imgBlurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale, (5, 5), 0)              # blur

imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgBlurred, 100, 200)                          # get Canny edges

cv2.namedWindow("imgOriginal", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)        # create windows, use WINDOW_AUTOSIZE for a fixed window size
cv2.namedWindow("imgCanny", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)           # or use WINDOW_NORMAL to allow window resizing

cv2.imshow("imgOriginal", imgOriginal)         # show windows
cv2.imshow("imgCanny", imgCanny)

cv2.waitKey()                               # hold windows open until user presses a key

cv2.destroyAllWindows()                     # remove windows from memory

return
```

#

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

python OpenCV_test1.py
  File "OpenCV_test1.py", line 4
    import cv2 import numpy as np import os

i have the same error